# Using Extract with request

Tags: php

I'm trying to save the values of POST and GET into a variable using extract.
However I'm not very sure why when I print out the values of session, it shows the values from the extracted REQUEST.

And when I put values inside the a variable like $username... I cannot get the last value I saved into it.

If I have this index.php?username=NAME

```
extract($_REQUEST);    
print_r($_SESSION); //Why this prints the values of request?

$username = "new username"
echo $username; //it still echos "NAME"
```

Comment: Please don't *extract* the variables! The default mode is `EXTR_OVERWRITE` which overwrites all existing variables. This is a big security hole!

Comment: I cannot think of any case in which what you demonstrate with `$username` should work. If you assign something to a variable, that variable should take that value, it should not stick to an old value. Is this literally the code with which you can reproduce this problem?!

Comment: Are you missing `;` after `$username = "new username"` in real code also?

Answer (score 0):

It may because of common named values in $_REQUEST and $_SESSION try

extract($_REQUEST,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,'any_prefix');

http://manaphp.blogspot.in/2013/08/do-you-want-to-show-arraynamed-values.html